# Install dlib in python3 on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, image-recognition, dlib

Getting the below as error:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.1.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/x1/bsml9c1532x102zlxhqt_k380000gn/T/pip-build-_1n6svbf/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x1/bsml9c1532x102zlxhqt_k380000gn/T/pip-0m_zvdwp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    error: Cannot find cmake, ensure it is installed and in the path.
    You can install cmake on OSX using `sudo brew install cmake`.
    You can also specify its path with --cmake parameter.

    ----------------------------------------
```

Then sudo brew install cmake is not installing as well.
Any solutions to this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use brew without sudo..

```
brew install cmake
```